# How to explain output of following Java code

Tags: java

This is the code I cannot understand it's answer. Please can someone explain this? I know lines 4,5 have an error. Therefore I want an explanation about lines 1,2,3. There is something special about " " in this:

```
byte b = 10;
short s = 100;
int x = 125;
long l = 15000;
float f = 1.5f;
double d = 21.231;
char c = 'c';
boolean bool = 10>9;
System.out.println(b+s+x+""+f+d+c+bool); //Line 1
System.out.println(""+b+s+x+f+d+c+bool); //Line 2
System.out.println(b+s+x+f+d+c+""+bool); //Line 3
System.out.println(b+s+x+f+d+c+bool+""); //Line 4
System.out.println(bool+b+f+d+c+""+x+l); //Line 5
```

Comment: You should be getting error "bad operand types for binary operator '+'", on Line 4 and Line 5. To fix just concat with `""+` on beggining of Line 4 and Line 5.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this code won't work because you can't add boolean variables with types like (int,byte,float,double) since boolean holds true or false